# Does a discussion of McTaggart's B series appear in continental philosophy?

Tags: time, continental-philosophy, mctaggart

I have thought about it, in my own terms, long enough to think that there's no A series.

But maybe this can inspire me to something more interesting, less analytic.

Do any continental philosophers write much on the B series as opposed to the A?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean by "A series" or "B series". Coming out of your own thought, with your own terms, would you mind giving us comprehendable descriptions of what you want to subsume under these terms?

Comment: @Philip Klöcking I assume the question refers to the philosophy of time by McTaggart. He discriminates A-series and B-series.

Comment: I don't know of any continental philosophers who have addressed the metaphysics of time. Typically continental philosophers who are interested in time are interested in the phenomenology--the experience of time and profess themselves utterly uninterested in the metaphysics.

Comment: @klocking: I admit I'd never heard of [McTaggart](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mctaggart/) before finding him on the SEP site; interestingly, given the question he was a 'dedicated interpreter and defender of Hegel'.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Funny enough, I would have named Hegel as implicitly historicizing as B-type. I know of a strong tradition of the philosophy of history in the 20th century in France, too, but cannot tell if they explicitly adress this destinction anywhere.

Comment: @klocking: unfortunately, because of McTaggarts distinctly unmemorable names I repeatedly forget which is which;). It's generally taken, that physically GR provides evidence for A; philosophically I'm inclined to B; whereas McTaggart inclined towards A; its a good question if that was in line with his own interpretation of Hegel - but I know no more than what is written in the SEP.

Comment: Right, so by his lights, lack of simultaneity, as shows up in Relativity means time does not exist.  That seems like a big jump, and can be dodged, as in Relativity itself, by making time relative to space and motion.  Kant's argument is much, much better.

Comment: @jobermark: I think it's worth keeping in mind too, that timelessness does not mean lack of change; there's a distinction between the two; and it's worth remembering Simultaniety fails for distant places but not for proximate places.

Comment: It's something that tripped me up, anyway.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  Simultaneity fails more the more distant the places, but it fails universally, it is only ever approximate, it does not exist.  McTaggert's proof is not nearly so coherent.  By the same standard he applies to events, there is no left or right, because what you are right or left of changes constantly, so you can apply leftness and rightness only by presuming them, and that is supposedly an infinite regress -- rather than an arbitrary decision.